# Mapping properties of beans in different packages using dozer

Tags: properties, javabeans, package, dozer

I'm trying to map properties of beans, which are in different packages, using dozer eg:

```
<mapping> 
 <class-a>com.naeem.schema.basictypes.Birth</class-a> 
 <class-b>com.naeem.schema.forms.n840.DateStore</class-b> 
  <field>
   <a>countryOfBirth</a>
   <b>countryOfBirth</b> 
 </field> 
</mapping>
```

is this possible in dozer. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Its possible in dozer.
By default, dozer will map all property from source object to same name property in destination object. So in your case both the class has a property  **countryOfBirth**  of same name. So you dont even have to write mapping file. Following will be suffice :

```
DozerMapper mapper = new DozerMapper();
Birth birth = new Birth();
//set different fields of birth object
DateStore dateStore =  new DateStore();
mapper.map(birth,dateStore);
```

Or,ulternatively,

```
DozerMapper mapper = new DozerMapper();
Birth birth = new Birth();
//set different fields of birth object
DateStore dateStore =  mapper.map(birth,DateStore.class);
```